# _.each wait till boolean condition has been met to loop around

Tags: loops, underscore.js

How can I achieve a loop like this:

```
foobar.each(function (model, j) {
   // asynchrounous call etc. {in here bool get set to true}

   // outside all asynchronous calls
   // wait till bool is true, without stopping anything else except the loop to the top of 
      the _.each
})
```

I asked a similar question yesterday. But it got marked as a duplicate when it wasn't the same case. Their solution did not achieve the same thing. Also generator functions were suggested which looked like it would work. But I can't use them with ecmascript 5

I've tried busy loops and set time out but they don't seem to work either

I've also tried this:

```
goto();

function goto() {
     if (foo === true) {
            //return true; /*I've tried with and without the return because the loops
                             doesn't need a return*/
     } else {
            goto();
     }
}
```

What happens with the goto() method is it breaks. Giving me the right results for the first iterations then execution seems to stop altogether. 'foo' always gets set to true in normal execution though.

Comment: Have a look at [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). There are a number of libraries out there if you can't use ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is implement a foreach yourself, where you execute your condition, and then on success callback go to the next item (but meanwhile the rest of the code will keep running.

```
var iteration = 0 //count the iteration of your asynchronous process


//start looping
loop(iteration)


function loop(iteration){

var model = foobar[iteration];

//exit your loop when all iterations have finished (assuming all foobar items are not undefined)
if (foobar[iteration] === undefined){
return;
}


//do what you want

//on success callback
iteration++;
loop(iteration);
//end success callback
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more please. Wouldn't that just execute something when the for each is finished. I need a pause on each _.each loop until a boolean value has been assigned to true.

Comment: Oh, I thought all calls needed to be finished. I will update the answer and explain, one sec

Comment: I'll try it now

Comment: Okay, it works the same way as before for the moment. I had my goto method the same as before except on true it now calls back to loop(). That's where it worked the same as before. With it set up like this: if (plinthPopulated === true) {
                        iteration++;
                        myLoop(iteration);
                    } else {
                          // What would go here instead, without a goto function?
                    }